# Azure devops pipeline removing " from parameter value in bash step

Tags: bash, shell, azure-devops

I am passing in a parameter to the pipeline as shown below -

```
parameters:
  - name: ListofValues
    displayName: values for test
    type: object
    default:
    - test:
      name: "test"
      desired: '"abc","xyz"'
```

When I am passing these values in bash step it is coming as
`"abc,xyz"` and I am expecting it to be `"abc","xyz"` is there a way I can fix this ?

values may look similar, kindly look for `"` after end of value 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `${{ convertToJson() }}` to keep the double quota.

My sample yaml(please notice the structure of test):

```
parameters:
  - name: ListofValues
    displayName: values for test
    type: object
    default:
      test:
        name: "test"
        desired: '"abc","xyz"'


trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo "${{ convertToJson(parameters.listOfValues.test.desired) }}"
```

Output value is bash task:
[image]

2. Or you can add `\` before quota for the value:

My sample yaml:

```
parameters:
  - name: ListofValues
    displayName: values for test
    type: object
    default:
      test:
        name: "test"
        desired: '\"abc\",\"xyz\"' 

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo ${{ parameters.ListofValues.test.desired }}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to know it' helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
var="abc,xyz"
IFS="," read -a array <<< $var
var=""
for word in "${array[@]}"; do
    var="$var\"$word\","
done
var="${var%,}"

echo "${var}"
# outputs:
# "abc","xyz"
```

Read the elements of `var` delimited by `,` into an array named `array`.
Then loop over the elements in the array and concatenate them into var while adding the required `"`.
At the end remove the extra trailing `,`.

This solution works with any number of elements.

Comment: yeah, but value of var is dynamic and can add many other values separated by ,